# Disable date/time to set automatically on windows phone 8

Tags: datetime, windows-phone-8, setting

I wonder if someone know if i can disable the option in settings to set date/time automatically on windows phone 8.

When application starting it disables if its on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no global setting that can be modified by a Windows Phone application. So what you're asking is impossible.

Comment: Thats bad. Because if i am driving between time zones and the clock was 0100 when i started i want the end time to be in the same zone even if the time is 2 hours ahead at the end destination. So by disableing the automatically time thing in settings it is solved. But how should i do when this not will work as you say

Comment: @RobinM Use `DateTime.UtcNow` to get the UTC time (independent of the time zone)

Comment: What happens if i have **UtcNow** and travel in to another time zone? Does it remember what time zone i was in when i started?

Comment: @RobinM It will give you the same time, no matter which timezone you are. That's what UTC is. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC You can either keep it as is (useful is you want to measure the elapsed time without having to care about the timezone), or convert it to your current timezone (that's what `DateTime.Now` is doing under the hood)

Comment: Ok. So what you are saying is that if i use **UtcNow** and travel between time zones it will be the same as when i started. I give you an example, lets say that you travel from USA and the clock is 0300 AM and fly to Russia i want the clock to be what it is in USA when i get to Russia, is that what **UtcNow** does, have i understod right?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers